# Search a file for a string and replace the next line with another string, not the expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file .sdf like this:

```
$$$$
compound1
#lots of text


$$$$
compound1
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2
#lots of text
```

I'm trying to rename all the compound names, which are basically the lines after `$$$$`, to include a counting number. The expected result is this:

```
$$$$
compound1_1
#lots of text


$$$$
compound1_2
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2_1
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2_2
#lots of text
```

The code I am using is:

```py
import sys
import re
import os
file = sys.argv[1]
file2 = file + '_fixed'
name2 = 'compound'
with open(file2,'w') as new_file:
    with open(file) as fp:
        # read all lines in a list
        for line in fp:
        # check if string present on a current line
            if "$$$$" in line:
                new_file.write(line)
                name = next(fp)
                if name2 != name:
                    name2 = name
                    j = 0
                    new_name = name + '_' + str(j)
                    new_file.write(new_name)
                else:
                    j = j + 1
                    new_name = name + '_' + str(j)
                    new_file.write(new_name)
            else:
                new_file.write(line)
```

But the output file is like this:

```
$$$$
compound1
_1 #lots of text


$$$$
compound1
_2 #lots of text

$$$$
compound2
_1 #lots of text

$$$$
compound2
_2 #lots of text
```

Appreciate any input!

Comment: When iterating over lines of a file the line ending newline character is included in the line. Replace `name + '_' + str(j)` by `name.rstrip() + '_' + str(j) + '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

A one possible solution using `re` + `defaultdict`:

```py
import re
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict


txt = '''\
$$$$
compound1
#lots of text


$$$$
compound1
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2
#lots of text
'''

d = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))

txt = re.sub(r'(?<=^\${4}\n)([^\n]+)', lambda g: f'{g[1]}_{next(d[g[1]])}', txt, flags=re.M)
print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
$$$$
compound1_1
#lots of text


$$$$
compound1_2
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2_1
#lots of text

$$$$
compound2_2
#lots of text
```